# Error with a folder security tab in Windows 10

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions, chkdsk, acl, icacls

On an external hard drive I have a folder which seems to have a problem.
When I use software on it I have some error message, the only program with can open this folder looks like to be the file explorer.
I try all the option of chkdsk possible and it found no error.
`takeown` and `icacls` say it can't find the file, but `dir` can list the folder.

When I go to property with the file explorer the folder size appearing is 0, but there is file on this folder I can see it with the explorer and open them (inside the folder everything looks OK) and in the security tab it shows an error message (and there is no Advanced option).

I tried everything I know, but I can't find a solution. I'm really surprise `chkdsk` find no error and everything inside the folder works perfectly.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: aux Properties]
<sup>**aux Properties**</sup>

Comment: Try to use Administrator account to access the Security tab. And give the administrators group ownership permission of the folder.

Comment: I can’t read anything in the screenshot but what might work is copying the file to another drive and then copying it back to the original drive (cut and paste).

Comment: @user52599 my account can be administrator (right click on app, then run as administrator) is this type of account is fine or should I create a new type of account?

Comment: @Ramhound when I try to copy the folder the progress bar program say it can't find the folder. But if I double click I can access it. The error message say "the security information is not available or not displayable"

Comment: @Fractale i mean you are not the member of the group that is designated as owner on the folder; Refer here to create a administrator account :https://www.top-password.com/blog/3-ways-to-create-new-administrator-account-in-windows-10/ ; Also adding to what Ramhound said - copy using robocopy :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy